# Function for Sheets getting error: ' Missing ) after argument list. (line 8, file "Code") '

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a function to shorten VLOOKUP in the sheet, since I have to use it many times in different cells. I am getting this error in the following code:

```
function find(a) {
    var q = VLOOKUP(a,Rooms:Capacities,2,FLASE)
    return q
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have altered the code to this, but I still get this error at the line defining q:

function getCapacity(a) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('codeDATA');
  var R = ss.getRange('A3:A58');
  var C = ss.getRange('B3:B58');
  var q = VLOOKUP(a,R:C,2,FALSE);
  return q;
  
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-write the script entirely, but it works now.

```
function getCapacity(a) {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('codeDATA');
  var R = data.getRange(1,1,data.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  var C = data.getRange(1, 2, data.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = 2; i < R.length; i++) {
      if (R[i][0] === a) {
       break
      }
    }
  return C[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess but could it be your function name. Sheets already has a find() function. Try changing the name to something like myfind(a)

Comment: I changed the name to getCapacity() after, still same error

Comment: I think the issue you have is that you can't use vlookup in a google script.  this answer may help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838294/writing-google-javascript-similar-to-vlookup